# Firebase Database suddenly returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Up until two days ago my code was working fine with no problems, out of the blue my code begins returning nil when I know for a fact that the value is there within my Firebase node. I have not touched the code in weeks nor have made anychanges to it any time recently. I have recently upgraded my Xcode to 9 but still running Swift 3.

I have the value `radiusDistanceNumber` declared above my `viewDidLoad()` as

```
class viewController: UIViewController {

var radiusDistanceNumber: Int()

override func viewDidLoad()
 super.viewDidLoad {

}
    func radiusValue(){
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        guard let uid = user?.uid else{
            return
        }
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(uid)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
            print("this is the snapshot value \(snapshot.value)")
            //returns correct value of 14
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.radiusDistanceNumber = dictionary["radiusDistance"] as? Int

                print(self.radiusDistanceNumber)
                //returns nil
                if self.radiusDistanceNumber == nil {
                    //let the user know it may be an error in connection
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(
                        title: "Error",
                        message: "Data not loading properly, make sure you have a strong connection and try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Got it", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else{
                // pass the value to the slider so the user can see the distance
                let radiusDistanceNumberFloat = Float(self.radiusDistanceNumber!)
                self.radiusSlider.value = radiusDistanceNumberFloat
                self.radiusLabel.text = String(self.radiusSlider.value)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Again, this code was working weeks ago

Comment: Is the snapshot.value equal to 14 on your line  print("this is the snapshot value \(snapshot.value)") ? If yes, why do you try to cast it as a dictionary in the next line ? If no, what is it equal to ? :)

Comment: I dont think above code should compile .Doesnt it give you the error at `var radiusDistanceNumber: Int()` ?

Comment: @Alex I have that there as a check for myself to make sure there is a value within my snapshot, and then I cast it as a dictionary because I have other values in my tree like "name","age","username" etc and "radiusDistance" is the one i'm looking for

Comment: @3stud1ant3 nope, it compiles normally

Comment: I tried it on playground and it gives me error I think you are declaring in `viewDidLoad()` differently , anyhow if it compiles correctly then can you please show the result of `print("this is the snapshot value \(snapshot.value)")`

Comment: if you try  `Any` instead of `AnyObject` in `if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]` , see what is the result?

Comment: I think you should change `var radiusDistanceNumber: Int()` to `var radiusDistanceNumber = Int()`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I apologize if I didn't explain properly how I declare radiusDistanceNumber, so I edited my question above for more clarity. Just tried it, and radiusDistanceNumber came back with nil

Comment: can you please show the result of `print("this is the snapshot value \(snapshot.value)")`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 changing it from :Int() to = Int() did the trick ! Submit it as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: Great , submitted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make these changes in your code . You are currently declaring the `radiusDistanceNumber` incorrectly so

Replace

```
var radiusDistanceNumber: Int()
```

with

```
var radiusDistanceNumber = Int()
```

I think you should also 
replace

`if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]`

with

`if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]`